# Excel parametric formula with JXLX

Tags: excel, jxls

I am using JXLX and need to add an Excel formula on a particular row. Rows' data ara populated from an array. My excel template is like this:

```
Name                 Total
------               --------
${array.name}        =SUMIF(Name,$A2,Data!$G2:$G10)
```

In this formula A2 represents product name and should change accordingly in every row i.e A3, A4 etc. Not really interesting but G2 and G10 is quantity data in different sheet whic works fine.

So how can I ca change A2 in every row?

Comment: Your saying that the equations are already in the cell or need to be populated?  About how many rows or sheets?

Comment: Equation is already in the cell its copied in every row by jxls. But A2 is same for all rows however I need incremental A's i.e. A3 A4 for following rows.

Answer (score 1):

Though I'm not sure I fully understand the question, but I see a couple of solutions:

1. Remove the '$' before A2 in the first cell and then drag/copy the cell to all rows below (lower right black box when cell is highlighted).
2. Assuming the question is more programming related because you have a routine and you don't wan't to do option #1 every time... Find and replace '$A2' in formulas with the correct row number.

   Assuming 'Total' column is 'B' and rows 1 thru 10.

   ```
   Sub LoopRange()
     Dim rCell As Range
     Dim rRng As Range
     Set rRng = Sheet1.Range("B1:B10")

     For Each rCell In rRng.Cells
       Dim row As String
       row = "$A" & rCell.row

       rCell.Replace What:="$A2", replacement:=row, LookAt:=xlPart, _
         SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
         ReplaceFormat:=True

     Next rCell
   End Sub
   ```